# Running database access on Glassfish 7.0 with intellij

Tags: java, database, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

I am having issues getting through the database access step on this project.  When I try the login on the webpage(which launches the try { code below) I get this error

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl can not implement com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Database, because it is not an interface (com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Database is in unnamed module of loader
```

I'm running with these dependencies which are the versions that were provided by my teacher for the project.  When I run this code off the server it seems to work just fine in a normal intellij project.

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
          <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
          <version>1.8.0.10</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.healthmarketscience.jackcess</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackcess</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>net.sf.ucanaccess</groupId>
          <artifactId>ucanaccess</artifactId>
          <version>4.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.1</version>
      </dependency>
```

Here is the code itself

```
try {
            System.out.println("LOADING THE DATABASE");

            //Load Driver - Step #1
            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");

            //Get Connection - Step #2
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/Josh/IdeaProjects/Java3Lab2/ChattBankMDB.mdb");

            //Create Statement - Step #3
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            //Execute Statement - Step #4
            String sql;
            sql = "select CustID, CustPassword " +
                    "from Customers " +
                    "where " + "CustID = " + id;
            System.out.println(sql);

            ResultSet rs;
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            //Process Data - Step #5
            String custIdCheck = "1";
            String custPassCheck = "1";

            while (rs.next()) {
                custIdCheck = rs.getString("CustID");
                custPassCheck = rs.getString("CustPassword");
            }

            if (custIdCheck.equals(id) && custPassCheck.equals(passw))
            {
                out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
                out.println("<html>");
                out.println("<head>");
                out.println("<title>LOGIN SERVLET</title>");
                out.println("</head>");
                out.println("<body>");
                out.println("<hi>VALID LOGIN</hi>");
                out.println("</body>");
                out.println("/html>");
                System.out.println("WINN");
            }

            else {
                out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
                out.println("<html>");
                out.println("<head>");
                out.println("<title>LOGIN SERVLET</title>");
                out.println("</head>");
                out.println("<body>");
                out.println("<hi>INVALID LOGIN</hi>");
                out.println("</body>");
                out.println("/html>");
            }

            //Close Connection - Step #6
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("PP: " + e);
        }
```

I can't figure out why I get this error.  It's not clear to me what I'm missing but maybe I need a different version of jackcess?  I have tried changing to different versions of ucanacces and jackcess to no avail.  Everything seems to run fine until I get to the login page and try the login button.  The system.out.println LOADING THE DATABASE runs so I know it's crashing right after that.

Comment: Post your `module-info.java` file.

Comment: You try to implement Database but it is apparently not an interface but a class

Comment: Can you check your IntelliJ project using the same JDK version as the GlassFish 7.0? GlassFish 7.0 Delivers Support for JDK 17 and Jakarta EE 10.